# How to get current trace id and span id from stackdriver nodejs lib

Tags: node.js, gcloud, trace, stackdriver

I am using @google-cloud/trace-agent library for nodejs for tracing. Once I start my tracer. I am able to see the traces in stackdriver console. Now I want to get the current traceId and spanId so that I can log it and map to my tracing data.

I am unable to find the api that provides the current trace context.

Comment: When using [getResponseTraceContext](https://github.com/googleapis/cloud-trace-nodejs/blob/6793b0993b6edeafbc9af9f4112b072b54943295/src/trace-api.ts#L344) you should be able to view [traceid and spanid](https://github.com/googleapis/cloud-trace-nodejs/blob/6793b0993b6edeafbc9af9f4112b072b54943295/src/trace-api.ts#L64)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this using getCurrentContextId() method.